# Pros and cons to create separate databases for each company

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework-5, iis-7.5

I am supposed to develop an enterprise-class ASP.NET Web Application that supports multiple companies.

What are the pros and cons to create separate databases for each company? Won’t it very resource consuming for a server to support connections to multiple databases or it’s better to have only one database? Let’s say I have 2000 companies and each of them has 100 employees.

What is the best approach to design the system in this case?

Comment: surely you should know this is going to be opinion based / too broad?!

Comment: surely you know he knows .... ? :)

Comment: One database is better in every respect, save for one: data security. How upset will your customers get when the day comes that a bug exposes one customer's data to another? Do you take the risk of saving time and money now at the possible expense of the business in the future or not? Weigh up the risks and make your choice.

Comment: Please elaborate if you downvoting I'm happy to rephrase/whatever, we need advice from people who have relative experience with given technologies stack

Comment: @tanner: I have own opinion so am not looking for just other opinions but need ones based on strong arguments based on given technologies, e.g IIS allocates particular processes per webapp, will them serve such load, will required and allocated ado.net connectivity related resources like pools/caches would be able serve such amount of connections in case of multiple DBs and how many memory would this require? (IIRC every DB will have own connection pool)

Comment: *Supports multiple companies* - if company is big, then they are usually free to demand own solution (specific to their needs). Solutions made for multiple **independent** companies **will** use separate environment (in your case database). If you make something what is simply **going to be used** by **independent** companies, then of course don't put their data into same database lol.

Comment: @ssl I flagged to close this as primarily opinion based. You even say it in your own comment :"I have own opinion so am not looking for just other opinions but need ones based on strong arguments based on given technologies". You're looking for opinions, which is off topic for SO.

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in the below links:

[Multi-Tenant Data Architecture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479086.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

[Stack Exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4547/designing-a-platform-one-database-or-multiple-databases)

[SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21844479/multiple-databases-vs-single-database-with-logically-partitioned-data)

Answer (score 0):

Pros: Much faster querying; better overall performance, security and scale-ability; easier fine tuning of each individual database, easier deployment and troubleshooting.

Cons: maintaining 2000 backup jobs